# Can you run a portable Windows installation with a usb drive on a Intel Chromebook?

Tags: windows, chromebook

I was wondering if I could make a portable Windows installation on a USB drive with Windows to go and use it together with my chromebook. Couldn't really find much information on this.

Is this possible? Has anyone done this?

Comment: Intel or ARM Chromebook?  If it an ARM processor then the answer is **NO** if its an Intel processor then it depends on the restrictions imposed by the OEM.

Comment: What kind of restrictions? Maybe also the lack of drivers.

Comment: It should be easy enough to verify if Windows can be ran on your device by doing a Google search.  What has your research shown?  Have you tried?  Are you stuck at a step?